# Spring injection in Filter implementation mapped in web.xml

Tags: java, spring, web.xml, servlet-filters

web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.mypackage.MyFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/myFilterPattern/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

MyFilter:

```
public class MyFilter implements Filter {

    @Autowired
    InjectedBean someInjectedBean;
```

However, when intercepting `/myFilterPattern/*` requests, `someInjectedBean` in `MyFilter.doFilter(...)` is still null, meaning it has not been injected. The same bean (`InjectedBean`) is injected fine in other context components that are not referenced in web.xml.

**Is it because container filtering takes place outside the Spring context? Is there any way to have Spring injection in Filter implementation mapped in web.xml?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Filter is not a spring bean(it is a web component) the injections won't work inside them. Springs wont inject inside web component.

use a DelegatingFilterProxy, this is a filter implementation that takes a springbean name as init param and delegates the filter request to that bean.

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>targetBeanName</param-name>
    <param-value>myFilterBean</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/myFilterPattern/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

And create a Bean with name myFilterBean in your spring context.

```
public class MyFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Autowired
    InjectedBean someInjectedBean;
 
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
      FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Comment: did you mean "create a Bean with name **myFilterBean** in your spring context" ?

Comment: Yes Create a bean with name myFilterBean of type MyFilter. MyFilter can extend GenericFilterBean.

Comment: what do you think the scope of that bean should be in the context ?  session ?

Comment: It can be singleton. Filters are created once at the app startup.

Comment: I did all of this and the container renders a blank page.  it doesn't go into `MyFilter`

Comment: Check the server logs. It should have thrown some error.?

Comment: nvrmnd -- i had the bean session scoped.  changed to singleton and it works

Answer (score 1):

One more solution if you are using spring security and extending the OncePerRequestFilter

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter{

    @Autowired
    ResourceConfig resourceConfig;

    public CustomAuthorizationFilter() {
            SpringBeanAutowiringSupport.processInjectionBasedOnCurrentContext(this);
    }
//...your code
```

its important to pull the details from resourceConfig in doFilterInternal block only so you will get values else you may end up at null pointer exception.