# How to solve OncePerRequestFilter abstract class Autowired getting null pointer exception?

Tags: java, spring-boot, servlets, jwt

I am using spring boot(2.2.0.RELEASE) JWT Authentication using OncePerRequestFilter abstract class.While autowired service class is getting null exception.I tried some ways but still getting same.Can any one help me for that issue.

**Code :**

```
@Component
    public class JwtRequestFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

        @Autowired
        private JwtUserDetailsService jwtUserDetailsService;
        @Autowired
        private JwtTokenUtil jwtTokenUtil;

        @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
                throws ServletException, IOException {    
            try {
                final String requestTokenHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
                String username = "";
                String jwtToken = "";            
                if (requestTokenHeader != null && requestTokenHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                    jwtToken = requestTokenHeader.substring(7);
                    try {
                         //here getting null pointer exception
                        username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken);
                        logger.info("username : " + username);
                    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                        logger.error("Unable to get JWT Token :: " + e.getMessage());                    
                    } catch (ExpiredJwtException e) {
                        logger.error("JWT Token has expired :: " + e.getMessage());                   
                    }
                } else {
                    logger.warn("JWT Token does not begin with Bearer String");
                }
                if (username != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
                    UserDetails userDetails = jwtUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);
                    if (jwtTokenUtil.validateToken(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                                userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                        usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
                                .setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(usernamePasswordAuthenticationToken);
                    }
                }
                chain.doFilter(request, response);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("JwtRequestFilter Exception :: " + e.getMessage());            
            }
        }
        }
```

---

This below posted code is another class.

```
 @Service
    @Component
    public class JwtTokenUtil implements Serializable {        
        private static final long serialVersionUID = -2550185165626007488L;                                               
        public String getUsernameFromToken(String token) {
            return getClaimFromToken(token, Claims::getSubject);
        }                       
    }
```

**Exception :**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.corenttech.engine.jwt.config.JwtRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(JwtRequestFilter.java:101)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:526)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:678)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1579)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**web.xml** This is my web.xml i have configured JwtRequestFilter

```
<web-app>   
    <filter>
        <filter-name>JwtRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.demo.engine.jwt.config.JwtRequestFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>JwtRequestFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/kb/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>       
</web-app>
```

Comment: what "autowire time service"?

Comment: That service class name is JwtUserDetailsService and JwtTokenUtil  @ Stultuske

Comment: While call that class methods getting null pointer exception

Comment: can you provide the stacktrace

Comment: so, the code that fails is not the code you've shown, but where you try to autowire this code?

Comment: I trying to call  username = jwtTokenUtil.getUsernameFromToken(jwtToken); this time getiing null

Comment: have you debugged your code to see what field is null? how do you instantiate your JwtRequestFilter?

Comment: I initiate JwtRequestFilter via web.xml @ Stultuske

Comment: Classes referenced in `web.xml` are instantiated using `new` by the servlet container (or rather using reflection, to be more exact), so auto-wiring doesn't happen. Only class instances created by the container are auto-wired.

Comment: Which class i need to add in web.xml JwtRequestFilter  or JwtUserDetailsService @Andreas

Comment: Give exact solution for me ,I m struggling last one week still facing same issue @Andreas

Comment: This answer shows what you need to do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43769987/5221149